# Xcode: how to I remove these blue borders around my labels and images?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, label, interface-builder

Just wondering how to I can remove these blue borders around my labels and images? Please see the attached, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Editor -> Canvas -> and click on -> Show bounded rectangles.

if this not work, repeat this step 3 times. this will resolve your issue.